# JavaScript Substring Backwards

Tags: javascript, substring

Is it possible to substring backwards. By that i mean i have a string like:

```
Test_Test_T_630
or
TestTest_Test_T_6305
or
TestTestTest_Test_T_63050
```

Would it be possible to to trim it to just accordingly:

```
Test_Test_T
or
TestTest_Test_T
or
TestTestTest_Test_T
```

I know you couldn't use the  substring to look for _T as this would trim too early, so could you do it backwards to look for the LAST underscore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourstring.slice(0, yourstring.lastIndexOf('_T')+2)
```

You could alternatively use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Based on a string of the form

```
var s = "TestTestTest_Test_T_ZZZ";
```

... you have various options to trim from the last underscore onwards. The simplest and probably best is:

```
s.slice(0, s.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

A more inefficient one:

```
s.split("_").slice(0, -1).join("_");
```

A short regex-based one:

```
s.replace(/_[^_]*$/, "");
```

Comment: I like the regex that you illustrated in the last example!